# No module named <module name>, deploying Worker container in Heroku

Tags: python, docker, heroku, containers, heroku-cli

I'm trying to use Heroku to deploy a simple python script that I have written and dockerized. I also added a `heroku.yml`.

Since this is a python script that I would like to run daily and not an API or a website, I concluded that the script should be deployed in Heroku worker container and not as a web container.

The containerized python script works locally on my own PC, but on heroku, the logs say:

```
2022-02-25T06:09:13.899148+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-02-25T06:09:13.930822+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-25T06:09:15.148500+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python -u main.py`
2022-02-25T06:09:15.790174+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-02-25T06:09:16.033414+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-02-25T06:09:16.033431+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
2022-02-25T06:09:16.033533+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from venmo_api import Client
2022-02-25T06:09:16.033552+00:00 app[worker.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'venmo_api'
2022-02-25T06:09:16.155312+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-25T06:09:16.232899+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

**I don't understand how the module isn't found when my Dockerfile says `COPY requirements.txt` and `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`**

For context, here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.10-alpine3.15
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "-u", "main.py"]
```

, my `requirements.txt`

```
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.11
idna==3.3
requests==2.27.1
urllib3==1.26.8
venmo-api==0.3.1
get-docker-secret==1.0.1
```

and my `heroku.yml`:

```
build:
  docker:
    worker: Dockerfile
```

All 3 of these files are in the same directory, and you can see `venmo-api` is in my requirements.txt.

---

Prior to deploying, I set the Heroku stack to container with: `heroku stack:set container`

I used `heroku config:set [redacted]` to set runtime environment variables like my API key

, and finally I ran `heroku container:push worker` and `heroku container:release worker` to build and push the python script image to Heroku's container registry and deploy it.

**Can someone please tell me where I went wrong? I just want this script to be able to run on the cloud and be able to schedule it to run daily with Heroku Scheduler?**

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Do you see your dependencies being installed when you build your container? Is `venmo-api` included in those dependencies?

Comment: [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris) , yes, I do see the dependencies being installed when I build the image. After running `heroku container:push`, I see the image building logs, and in there are `=> [4/6] COPY requirements.txt .` and `=> [5/6] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: That only answers half of my question. When you see `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` you should also see detailed output of that command, right? Is `venmo-api` included in the dependencies being installed?

Comment: [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris), sorry about that, yes, `venmo-api` is included in the dependencies being installed. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/6SXgDZ0.png)